# Selecting the last TabItem when new items are added to a TabControl's ItemSource using MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have created a dynamically generated `TabControl` by binding `ItemsSource` to `MyUnicornsViewModel`.

As new items are added to `MyUnicornsViewModel`... new tab items are created.  However, the newly added tabs are not automatically selected in the `TabControl`.

**How can I get new tabs to be selected when they are added?**

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyUnicornsViewModel}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- header template -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <!-- body template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

At first, I was hoping there was an event for "ItemsChanged" or "ItemAdded" in the `TabControl`, that way I can set the SelectedIndex in the code-behind as new items are added.

Another thing I tried was to bind the `TabControl.SelectedItem` to a `SelectedItem` property in `MyUnicornsViewModel`.  Sadly, that didn't work either.

<sub>**MyUnicornsViewModel:**</sub>

```
public class MyUnicornsViewModel : ObservableCollection<UnicornViewModel>
{
    ...

    private void AddNewUnicorn()
    {
        var awesomeUnicorn = new UnicornViewModel();
        Add(awesomeUnicorn);
        SelectedItem = awesomeUnicorn;  //I expected my TabControl to have 'awesomeUnicorn' selected.
    }

    public UnicornViewModel SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. It's very odd to derive a "view model" from `ObservableCollection`. A view model should *contain* an observable collection.
2. View models need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface; it's not clear from the code provide if `UnicornViewModel` implements this interface, however, `MyUnicornsViewModel` absolutely does not.

Here's some suggestions:

1. A view model base class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface will really help get you most of the way.  You can write your own using the [INotifyPropertyChanged documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0) or look for an MVVM framework that fits well with your project (e.g. [Prism](https://prismlibrary.com), [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.net), [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net)).  Each of these will provide a base class to use for view models - `BindableBase`, `ViewModelBase`, `ReactiveObject` respectively for each of the frameworks above.
2. `MyUnicornsViewModel` should have:

   - An `ObservableCollection` for the collection of unicorns; this will be bound to the `ItemsSource` property on your `TabControl`.
   - The `SelectedItem` property must fire the `PropertyChanged` event when set.

Here's a quick sample using Prism:

```cs
public sealed class UnicornViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public UnicornViewModel(string name, string content)
    {
        Name = name;
        Content = content;
    }

    // these properties don't change and therefore don't need to raise property changed
    public string Name { get; }

    public string Content { get; }
}

public sealed class UnicornsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private UnicornViewModel _selectedUnicorn;

    public UnicornsViewModel()
    {
        AddUnicornCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddUnicorn);
        ClearUnicornsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClearUnicorns, () => HasUnicorns).ObservesProperty(() => HasUnicorns);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UnicornViewModel> Unicorns { get; } = new ObservableCollection<UnicornViewModel>();

    public UnicornViewModel SelectedUnicorn
    {
        get => _selectedUnicorn;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedUnicorn, value, () => RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(HasUnicorns)));
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddUnicornCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand ClearUnicornsCommand { get; }
    private bool HasUnicorns => Unicorns.Any(); // helper property for the clear command's can execute

    private void AddUnicorn()
    {
        Unicorns.Add(new UnicornViewModel($"Unicorn {Unicorns.Count + 1}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
        SelectedUnicorn = Unicorns.Last();
    }

    private void ClearUnicorns()
    {
        SelectedUnicorn = null;
        Unicorns.Clear();
    }
}
```